# Chrome Extension content script on iframe without src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script which is injecting an iframe into my page's DOM.  This iframe does not have a src attribute, I am creating it dynamically with it's content's like...

```
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
```

How can I run my content script on this iframe? or communicate to the background? I need to trigger a "close my iframe" event from this code.  I know it is possible because honey is doing this.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/honey/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj?hl=en-US

Comment: I don't think this is possible; access to `data:` URLs cannot be obtained. Why do you think "honey is doing this"?

Comment: @Xan , because I have their extension installed and I see them adding a data: iframe, then interacting with the content script from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot run a content script in a frame at a `data:`-URL ([crbug.com/55084](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55084)).

There are some alternatives though:

1. In the page that embeds the frame, use the `onmessage` event to subscribe to events from the iframe, and insert a script in the data-URL frame that calls [`parent.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

   ```js
   // Content script in parent frame.
   // Assuming that variable iframe exists, and that it is an iframe.
   window.addEventListener('message', onMessage);
   function onMessage(event) {
       if (event.source === iframe && event.message === 'close') {
           window.removeEventListener('message', onMessage); // Clean-up
           iframe.remove();
       }
   }

   // In the iframe
   parent.postMessage('close');
   ```
2. Use [`.srcdoc`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-iframe-srcdoc) instead of .src+data URLs to load HTML in an iframe:

   ```js
   iframe.srcdoc = html;
   ```

   The HTML will be at the same origin as the parent document, so the content within the frame can simply use something like `frameElement.remove();` to remove the frame ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/4dr8j9mc/)).
   Since this script can directly access the parent page, the `html` that you insert must be trustworthy. Do NOT insert arbitrary HTML from untrusted sites!
3. Declare an extension page in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources), and load the extension page in the frame. Then you can use the [extension messaging APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate between the frame and the background of the extension. Unlike the previous methods, the code in this page runs in the origin of your extension, so you have access to some Chrome APIs (including extension messaging or [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)) and origin-specific data (such as localStorage).

   ```js
   iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('name_of_your_page.html');
   ```

Comment: This was very helpful, I went with the first solution.

Comment: appears this has changed with the introduction of match_about_blank option?

Comment: @rogerdpack Not in Chrome, `data:`-URIs have a unique origin, so they cannot be scripted by the parent page.